# $rootScope:infdig after randomizing ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, random, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to randomize my filtered data from Firebase. Unfortunetaly, after using my orderBy: random, I receive error with $rootScope:infdig. I read about it, but I can't figure out how can I solve it and randomize my output from Firebase. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places | filter: {cheap: 'true'} | limitTo: 4 | orderBy: random" class="col-lg-3">
```

JS:

```
// Random order by
   $scope.random = function() {
     return 0.5 - Math.random();  
   };
```

I'd be very grateful if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. I have created [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/yL8daar3/1/) with your case, but its working

But you can try look at [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider) also you can try increase iteration limit

```
 $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(15); // or something
```

Comment: Yes, it's strange. And more stranger is that sometimes when I refresh site everything is fine and when I refresh it again, I receive an error...

Comment: Why you can't shuffle your places inside controller? Not in a view

Comment: I think about it, but I have no idea how can I do it.